# Invoking keyboard keys, through proc - procedure (function) in tcl

Tags: linux, tcl, bind, tk-toolkit, sendkeys

In front of the internet, I could only find so far, just the reverse where the key-related event is associated with the front-end button, not the front-end button that invokes a key. Understood ?! Look:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish

button .b1 -text Hello -underline 0
button .b2 -text World -underline 0
bind . {.b1 flash; .b1 invoke}
bind . {.b2 flash; .b2 invoke}
pack .b1 .b2
```

Explanation - If you press a H button, the Hello button will blink. And the same effect happens with W; World

I want the Front-end [GUI] button to simulate the keystroke, for example - F1

[image]

> This Print Screen software is mp3blaster - [learn more..](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/mp3blaster/en/)

---

> This Print Screen is a GUI what are developer are work:

[image]

I asked that question a week or two ago. Since I did not get any
plausible answer, I do not know if it is possible, or no one knows, or
nobody cares.

I want to send a non tcl / tk application under UNIX GNU / Linux some keys
for a very simple toolbar control. For the application must be
the same as if these keys were hit on the keyboard. In VisualBasic
The function is called SendKey. Is it possible to do this with tcl / tk?

I will describe how to do this using Windows Script Host and tcom:

- Windows Script Host 2.0 beta (which you can download from
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/scripting/windowshost/beta/) includes a COM
  object that implements a SendKeys function.
- tcom 1.7 (available at http://www.vex.net/~cthuang/tcom/) is a
  Windows-specific Tcl extension that allows Tcl scripts to access
  COM objects.

In this example, the Tcl script starts Notepad and sends keys to the application.

package requires tcom

```
configure wshShell [:: tcom :: bind "WScript.Shell"]
set taskId [$ wshShell Run "notepad.exe"]
$ wshShell AppActivate $ taskId
after 500
$ wshShell SendKeys "The quick brown fox jumped \ n"
$ wshShell SendKeys "{TAB} about the lazy dog."
:: tcom :: release $ wshShell
```

---

On UNIX; Linux how to accomplish this ??? It would be by `focus` method, inverse `bind` or third party application `xvkbd`, `xbindkeys`, `xkeycaps`, `xev`, `xjoypad` etc ... Which to use and how to use if tcl/tk does not have one built-in command?!

If somebody knows and/or can clarify me, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdotool` (http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) could help with that task.

Here's a short snippet that sends `Ctrl+Tab` to Chrome when clicking a Tk button:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish

#
# Focus window named $window_name and send the specified key sequence.
#
proc send_key {window_name key_sequence} {
    foreach wid [exec xdotool search --name $window_name] {
        if {![catch {exec xdotool windowfocus $wid}]} {
            exec xdotool key $key_sequence
        }
    }
}

button .f1 \
    -text "Send Ctrl+Tab to Chrome (cycle through browser tabs)"  \
    -command {send_key chrome ctrl+Tab}
pack .f1
```

It's a bit problematic that you have to focus the window before you can send key sequences to it.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a key, you need the [`event generate` command](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/event.htm).

```
event generate $w <KeyPress-F1> -x $x -y $y
```

You probably want to direct the event to the focus window, and the X and Y locations ought to be set to 0,0 if you don't have a better place (or alternatively use the -`rootx` and `-rooty` options and the `winfo pointerxy` command to use global coordinates).

There are many other fields you can set for a key-press event, but most of them aren't commonly used. (In particular, I think it's easier to set up the state field using modifiers to the event being generated rather than explicitly setting the `-state` option.)